# Returning sublist maxes in Python - Problem with predict_proba?

Tags: python, max, nested-lists, naivebayes

I have a list of lists in Python, and I'm trying to place the max of each sublist into its own list. I've found multiple solutions online that seem like they should work for this, but I keep getting this error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. This may be due to how the nested lists were created in the first place (from a MultinomialNB model).

Here are the details around the code.

I've created a MultinomialNB model.

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()
```

I've fit it to data and am using it to predict classification probabilities for new data. I output the probabilities to a list, which creates a nested list:

```
pred = nb_classifier.predict_proba(stuff_to_assign).tolist()
```

This seems to work fine, and it appears to create a list of lists. The "pred" output looks like this:

```
[[0.9679623959303013,
  0.0004919066096350094,
  0.0025707756884416877,
  0.00543455013719153,
  0.009417511656556068,
  0.004419688570339585,
  0.0056471363437299105,
  0.004056035063805071],
 [0.002845247494316791,
  0.000370155483232512,
  0.9749812181697922,
  0.004089452129289453,
  0.007086596337192678,
  0.00332577754892364,
  0.004249421417094243,
  0.003052131420158753]]
```

I confirmed that this is a list:

```
type(pred)
List
```

What I want to do is grab the max value in each sublist and put it in its own list. Ideal output:

```
[0.9679623959303013,0.9749812181697922]
```

I've already tried:

```
maxes = [max(p) for p in pred]
```

And I get "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable." Any ideas on how to get my desired outcome? Is this just a nested list issue, or is it strictly due to my nested lists being created off of a model?

Comment: what is type(pred[0]) ?

Comment: See below.

Hypothetically my code should have worked, but I had already named something "pred" in my code previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `[ max(val) for val in zip(*pred) ]` should work.

I'd expect your code to return two values; the max of the first list and the max of the second list. The error suggests that you have assigned a list to `max` somewhere.

Comment: This was it... so my post is actually a bit useless.

"maxes = [max(p) for p in pred]" actually works, but I had defined something else as "pred" earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a nested list, to access the first list within `pred` you need to run `pred[0]`. To access the second list, run `pred[1]`

To get the maximum, run `max(pred[0])` and `max(pred[1])` respectively.

Your final code would like something like this

```
new_list = []
for i in range(2):
    new_list.append(max(pred[i]))
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
new_list = [max(pred[i]) for i in range(2)]
```